# Raising Event Not Working - C#

Tags: c#, events

Can't seem to get this to work not sure why.

Have this on one of my classes:

```
    public event Action CloseWindowEvent = delegate { };

    private void Close()
    {
        CloseWindowEvent();
    }
```

On another class i'm subscribed:

```
    remarkViewModel.CloseWindowEvent += CloseRequested;
```

The method never gets called:

```
    private void CloseRequested()
    {
        dialog.CloseDetailDialog();
    }
```

Thank you.

Comment: Why are you declaring it as an `Action` and not something standard like `public event EventHandler CloseWindowEvent;`?

Answer (score 1):

In C #, events must be invoked, and in addition, they have two predefined parameters:

**object sender and EventArgs e**

Here **this keyword** refers to the object that triggers the event and **EventArgs.Empty** sends empty arguments to that event, you can also instantiate the class by replacing **EventArgs.Empty** with **new EventArgs**

```
public event EventHandler CloseWindowEvent;

private void CloseEvent()
{
    CloseWindowEvent?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

where

```
remarkViewModel.CloseWindowEvent += CloseRequested;

private void CloseRequested(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you check the code where the Call to Close() method happens. I dont see any theoretical error in your code. See it works on a simplified model:

[image]

Comment: Definitely being called, attached a picture.

Comment: I think i'm going to end up not raising an event since I can't make it work. I'll just make that dialog class static and use that to close. I tried it on a different project with the event and it works fine. Not sure why not this time.

Comment: @Deadfish - During Debug check the Method & Target properties on your event. They should point to the Method attached and the Target should be the object used during assignment. May be you will find some clue there.

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely being called. Here's a snapshot of the event being raised.

[image]

Comment: Would you consider checking my post?